# Variance of scalar function of 2 random variables

Tags: probability, distributions, variance

Suppose I have a scalar function $g(X,Y)$, where $X$ and $Y$ are jointly distributed with pdf $p(x,y)$. I think the expected value of $g$ is given by

$$ \mathbb{E}[g] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x,y) p(x,y) dx dy $$

But what is the Var$[g]$?

Comment: By definition it's $\operatorname{Var}(g) = E[g^2] - E[g]^2.$  What are you looking for in addition to that?

Comment: That helps, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the definition, it works out to be

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty g^2(x,y) p(x,y) dx dy - \mathbb{E}[g] $$

which is equivalent to

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left( g(x,y) - \mathbb{E}[g] \right)^2 p(x,y) dx dy  $$